# How to fix this Undefined addEventListener error

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and i am trying to understand why my addEventListener method is not working? What i am trying to do is to create a delete button that deletes a posted array from my input. The array is nested in a mat-card tag and has an element reference that i called with view child in my typescript. The error i am getting is:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
>       at PostsComponent.ngAfterViewInit.

This is the code:

Post Component HTML

```
<mat-card #cardRef [notes] ="inputField" class="inputField">    
  <ul>
    <li>
      {{inputField.name}}
      {{inputField.department}}
      {{inputField.message}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button (click)="removeList()">Delete</button>
</mat-card>
```

Post Service

```
export class PostService

    public inputField = []

    removeDiv(id){
      const i = this.inputField.findIndex(res => res.id === id);
      if (i !== -1) {
        this.inputField.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }
}
```

Post Component.ts

```
export class PostsComponent {
    constructor(private Posts: PostService){}

    public inputField = [];    
    list;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.cardRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('click',  
        this.removeList.bind(this))
    }

    removeList(){
      this.Posts.removeDiv(this.inputField.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. Why are you using `addEventListener` instead of `(click)`? Is `inputField` an array or an object? It is declared as an object, but you are calling some properties on it as if it were an object.

Comment: I have the mat-card reference with cardRef to access the DOM/html i used the view child option that i initialized in the ngAfterViewInit, i guess i don't have to call the addEventListener but  how do i refer back to the html div (mat-card) i am trying to delete when the button is clicked.

Comment: You are right it should be an object not an array

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you do not want to display the `<mat-card>` component after the `removeList()` function is run.

Angular is all about building the DOM dynamically based on your state / model. As far as I see it, this is no different. It's not a case of "deleting the element" from the DOM, but rather telling Angular whether or not it should be in the DOM at any given time.

So surely it's just a case of using `*ngIf`?

Store the state of whether or not the `<mat-card>` should be hidden (default false) in the component, and update that to true when the event handler runs. Bind `*ngIf` to this property to allow Angular to remove it from the DOM when true.

component.ts

```
export class PostsComponent {
  hideList = false;

  removeList() {
    this.hideList = true;
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<mat-card *ngIf="!hideList">
  <button (click)="removeList()">Delete</button>
</mat-card>
```