# Pushing an object in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to push objects to display in matcards in angular.So every input there is a card that holds the three fields. What i have so far that does not work: I am getting an error that says `this.inputField.push is not a function at PostsComponent.getInput`

my Html:

```
       <input type="text" placeholder="Your name"  name="name" id="inputField1" [(ngModel)]="inputField.name">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Department" name="department" id="inputField2" [(ngModel)]="inputField.department" >
       <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message" name="message" value="" id="inputField3" [(ngModel)]="inputField.message" ></textarea>
       <button  (click)="getInput()">Post</button>
   </mat-card> 

   <mat-card *ngIf= "hiddenList"  [notes] ="inputField" class="inputField"  >
        <ul *ngIf="show" >
                <li *ngFor= "let input of inputField">
                    {{inputField.name}}
                    {{inputField.department}}
                    {{inputField.message}}
                </li>
              </ul>
  <button type="button" (click)="removeList()">Delete</button>
   </mat-card>
```

Component Ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InputField } from '../posts/posts'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss']
})
export class PostsComponent {
hiddenList=false

inputField: InputField[] = [];

getInput(){
     this.show = true
     this.inputField.push({'name':this.name, 'department':this.department, 'message':this.message})
     }

removeList(){
   this.hiddenList = true
  }
}
```

Post.ts:

```
export interface InputField{
 name: string,
 department: string, 
 message: string
}
```

Comment: So my answer to your last question helped you then? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354552/5367916

Comment: Yes it probably will but i need to declare my object before i can test it out. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the whole ts file code.

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to replicate the issue? (Looks fine at first glance) Also, are `this.department` and `this.message` defined in the .ts file?

Comment: Ok...i have defined them in the separate component Post.ts which is an interface that i imported into the component.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Couldn't replicate the issue you are facing; hence requested for a stackblitz.

Comment: stackblitz is proving to be a pain, one minute i can't import src the next it is telling me my path is not working.

Comment: Just added the solution with description and complete code, please let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and found out there are couple of mistakes. Please find the complete code here, I have created a working stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw5rrv

Just for your growth, i am listing mistakes here:

- you are using `inputField` with ngModel of inputs which is incorrect. As we want to store values in `inputField` Array, we need some other variable for binding with ngModel(`fieldData` is i have created).
- you should use template input variable(`input` in your case) inside *ngFor but you are using inputField.

  - I have also removed unnecessary code
  - I have used div instead of mat-card just for simplicity

Please let me know if any questions.

Comment: Thanks! this really helped. I am wondering though why we have to call the object then an array?fieldData: InputField ={
   name:"",
   department:"",
   message:""
 };  can't we just push to the object? or we are defining the array for the delete?

Comment: I have created an object with same property names as needed by the array for type matching. And second we are doing two things here: 1. we want to bind an object with input fields, so i created an object for binding. Now whenever values in input fields changes, my object (fieldData) updates itself. 2. We need to store these objects in an array so created a seperated array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your variable in the constructor.

```
constructor(){
    this.inputField = [];
}
```

Comment: because of the object you want to insert in the array. {'name':this.name, 'department':this.department, 'message':this.message} "this" keyword is your component here and in cant find any variable with department and name and message

Comment: but it is taking an input from my html

Comment: ok now I saw. there a missunderstood about form binding. inputField is an array but you want to use it both your form model and something else. create an other variable for form model

Answer (score 0):

You bind to inputField properties like inputField.name, inputField.department,
But in the declaration you say it is an array. And then you initialize it to an empty array.

You should have 2 properties:

```
inputFields: InputField[] = [] 
inputField: InputField = {}
```

for the current data you edit.

and then you can push the currently edited inputField to the inputFields array.

```
this.inputFields.push(this.inputField);
```

(my previous answer got downvoted but I still think you should use ; at the end of your statements :-) )